# My textarea is not logging the output correctly

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a checklist program, and to do that i need an input to log it's received value to a textarea, that part works fine, it's just that the when the value is logged to the textarea, it is placed right in the middle of the box, and the words go off the marked zone and do not break onto the next line. I have tried things like: (word-wrap: break-word), and setting the max width but nothing works. Thanks for the help

```
function transfer(){
var move = document.getElementById('chg').value;
document.getElementById('into').value = move;
```

}

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="comp.js"> </script>
    <style>
    #into{ height: 200px; width: 100px; position: absolute margin-top: 100px; word-wrap: break-word}
    #clicker{ margin-left: -1px; margin-top: 22px; position: absolute}
    #chg{position: absolute}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="text" id="chg" placeholder="Add events and reminders"/>
        <input type="textarea" id="into"/>
        <input type="button" onclick="transfer()" value="Add" id="clicker"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: better if show your code here, or make a fiddle,

Comment: How are you setting it to wrap the lines?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `padding-right:` to textarea

`#into{ padding-right: 30px; height: 200px; width: 100px; position: absolute margin-top: 100px;}`

Comment: sorry but for some reason i can't share my code even though i indent by four spaces